# Как выбрать опорный элемент для QuickSort без рандома?

Tags: c++, pivot

Суть заключается в том, что в основном все используют формулу:
mid = arr[L + rand()%(R-L-1)].
Есть ли какие-то способы выбрать "по-настоящему" средний элемент как опорный?

Comment: Есть. Только тогда слово Quick из названия придется убрать...

Comment: над этим все ломают голову и регулярно всплывают очередные "супер оптимизации", где находят "новый способ" найти более подходящий опорный элемент. Но по факту оказывается, что их "новый крутой способ" подходит только для каких то определённых входных данных.

Comment: есть алгоитм какого то крутого поиска пивота, но по факту, проще брать средний элемент, а лучше пользоваться sort() и не морочить голову

Comment: Насколько помню, Кнут в качестве разделителя рекомендовал брать медиану из 3-х (2-х крайних и среднего)

Comment: @avp, спасибо, это то, что я искал!

Comment: Очень хорошо, попробуйте протестировать на своих данных